# Opening my own profile page causes a "Something bad happened!" error

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, 500-server-error

Attempting to navigate to my own profile page on any site in the network throws an error.

Here's a .gif for full disclosure:

[image: The horror! Clicking on the profile link in the topbar and getting the "Oops! Something bad happened!" page]

Navigating to **anyone else's** profile page is fine, though.

Did someone break the "Don't deploy on Friday" rule?

Comment: Could reproduce.

Comment: Can't reproduce now ...  I can repro for my own account ...

Comment: I can reproduce on my account, but going to Spevacus's (https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/622284/spevacus) works fine, then breaks if I switch to the "Activity" tab.

Comment: I've reproduced on my own account (using Firefox on Windows).

Comment: Same symptoms here - only seen on Meta SE so far, can visit my profile on other sites without issue.

Comment: Happens on other sites as well (SO in my case).

Comment: Now also reproduced on my own account *and* another user's account on [scifi.se].

Comment: @JanWichelmann Yep, looks like it just spread to the rest of the network.

Comment: @JanWichelmann Yep - happening on other network sites now (Have tried SO, TWP and MedSci SE)

Comment: The issue here is the Activity tab, not the profile itself. Navigating to your own profile automatically puts you on the Activity tab.

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow Looks like it - if I navigate to another user's Activity tab it breaks

Comment: We're investigating. It's widespread across all profile pages.

Comment: @Taryn seems fixed now. I can see my own on MSE and SO again.

Comment: @TylerH We rolled back the build. :)

Comment: @Taryn I'll call that a fix any day ;-)

Comment: How did you make the GIF btw?

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur I use a program called ShareX.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We pushed a change out that was behind a feature flag. Unfortunately, we missed a page that needed to check for that setting...the profile page.

We've rolled back the build in the meantime, while we fix the issue.

Thanks for the report.